# How do I determine k when using k-means clustering?

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means

I've been studying about [k-means clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering), and one thing that's not clear is how you choose the value of k.  Is it just a matter of trial and error, or is there more to it?

Comment: Ah ah...  That's really _the_ question (about k-mean).

Comment: can you share the code for the function L (log likelihood)? 

Given a center at X,Y and points at (x(i=1,2,3,4,...,n),y(i=1,2,3,4,..,n)), how do I get L?

Comment: a link to Wikipedia article on the subject: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determining_the_number_of_clusters_in_a_data_set

Comment: I've answered a similar Q with half a dozen methods (using `R`) over here: stackoverflow.com/a/15376462/1036500

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You can maximize the Bayesian Information Criterion (BIC):

```
BIC(C | X) = L(X | C) - (p / 2) * log n
```

where `L(X | C)` is the log-likelihood of the dataset `X` according to model `C`, `p` is the number of parameters in the model `C`, and `n` is the number of points in the dataset.
See ["X-means: extending *K*-means with efficient estimation of the number of clusters"](http://www.aladdin.cs.cmu.edu/papers/pdfs/y2000/xmeans.pdf) by Dan Pelleg and Andrew Moore in ICML 2000.

Another approach is to start with a large value for `k` and keep removing centroids (reducing k) until it no longer reduces the description length.  See ["MDL principle for robust vector quantisation"](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s100440050015) by Horst Bischof, Ales Leonardis, and Alexander Selb in *Pattern Analysis and Applications* vol. 2, p. 59-72, 1999.

Finally, you can start with one cluster, then keep splitting clusters until the points assigned to each cluster have a Gaussian distribution.  In ["Learning the *k* in *k*-means"](http://books.nips.cc/papers/files/nips16/NIPS2003_AA36.pdf) (NIPS 2003), Greg Hamerly and Charles Elkan show some evidence that this works better than BIC, and that BIC does not penalize the model's complexity strongly enough.

Comment: Great answer!  For X-Means, do you know if overall BIC score n := k*2 (k clusters, each cluster modeled by Gaussian with mean/variance parameters).  Also if you determine the "parent" BIC > "2 children" BIC would you ever split that cluster again in the next iteration?

Comment: @Budric, these should probably be separate questions, and maybe on stats.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 38):

Basically, you want to find a balance between two variables: the number of clusters (*k*) and the average variance of the clusters. You want to minimize the former while also minimizing the latter. Of course, as the number of clusters increases, the average variance decreases (up to the trivial case of *k*=*n* and variance=0).

As always in data analysis, there is no one true approach that works better than all others in all cases. In the end, you have to use your own best judgement. For that, it helps to plot the number of clusters against the average variance (which assumes that you have already run the algorithm for several values of *k*). Then you can use the number of clusters at the knee of the curve.

Answer (score 28):

Yes, you can find the best number of clusters using Elbow method, but I found it troublesome to find the value of clusters from elbow graph using script. You can observe the elbow graph and find the elbow point yourself, but it was lot of work finding it from script.

So another option is to use [Silhouette Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determining_the_number_of_clusters_in_a_data_set) to find it. The result from Silhouette completely comply with result from Elbow method in R.

Here`s what I did.

```
#Dataset for Clustering
n = 150
g = 6 
set.seed(g)
d <- data.frame(x = unlist(lapply(1:g, function(i) rnorm(n/g, runif(1)*i^2))), 
                y = unlist(lapply(1:g, function(i) rnorm(n/g, runif(1)*i^2))))
mydata<-d
#Plot 3X2 plots
attach(mtcars)
par(mfrow=c(3,2))

#Plot the original dataset
plot(mydata$x,mydata$y,main="Original Dataset")

#Scree plot to deterine the number of clusters
wss <- (nrow(mydata)-1)*sum(apply(mydata,2,var))
  for (i in 2:15) {
    wss[i] <- sum(kmeans(mydata,centers=i)$withinss)
}   
plot(1:15, wss, type="b", xlab="Number of Clusters",ylab="Within groups sum of squares")

# Ward Hierarchical Clustering
d <- dist(mydata, method = "euclidean") # distance matrix
fit <- hclust(d, method="ward") 
plot(fit) # display dendogram
groups <- cutree(fit, k=5) # cut tree into 5 clusters
# draw dendogram with red borders around the 5 clusters 
rect.hclust(fit, k=5, border="red")

#Silhouette analysis for determining the number of clusters
library(fpc)
asw <- numeric(20)
for (k in 2:20)
  asw[[k]] <- pam(mydata, k) $ silinfo $ avg.width
k.best <- which.max(asw)

cat("silhouette-optimal number of clusters:", k.best, "\n")
plot(pam(d, k.best))

# K-Means Cluster Analysis
fit <- kmeans(mydata,k.best)
mydata 
# get cluster means 
aggregate(mydata,by=list(fit$cluster),FUN=mean)
# append cluster assignment
mydata <- data.frame(mydata, clusterid=fit$cluster)
plot(mydata$x,mydata$y, col = fit$cluster, main="K-means Clustering results")
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Just adding a link to the Silhouette Analysis tutorial for python users
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_silhouette_analysis.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-kmeans-silhouette-analysis-py

Comment: Also, for plotting see yellow brick https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/api/cluster/silhouette.html they also have the elbow method

Answer (score 13):

May be someone beginner like me looking for code example. information for **silhouette_score**
is available [here.](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score.html)

```py
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score

range_n_clusters = [2, 3, 4]            # clusters range you want to select
dataToFit = [[12,23],[112,46],[45,23]]  # sample data
best_clusters = 0                       # best cluster number which you will get
previous_silh_avg = 0.0

for n_clusters in range_n_clusters:
    clusterer = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters)
    cluster_labels = clusterer.fit_predict(dataToFit)
    silhouette_avg = silhouette_score(dataToFit, cluster_labels)
    if silhouette_avg > previous_silh_avg:
        previous_silh_avg = silhouette_avg
        best_clusters = n_clusters

# Final Kmeans for best_clusters
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=best_clusters, random_state=0).fit(dataToFit)
```

Comment: Sample doesn't work on scikit-learn version: 0.24.2. Error on silhouette_score (dataToFit, cluster_labels).
"Exception has occurred: ValueError
Number of labels is 3. Valid values are 2 to n_samples - 1 (inclusive)"

Comment: You should probably look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51382250/valueerror-number-of-labels-is-1-valid-values-are-2-to-n-samples-1-inclusiv

Answer (score 9):

Look at [this](http://books.nips.cc/papers/files/nips16/NIPS2003_AA36.pdf) paper, "Learning the k in k-means" by Greg Hamerly, Charles Elkan. It uses a Gaussian test to determine the right number of clusters. Also, the authors claim that this method is better than BIC which is mentioned in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

There is something called Rule of Thumb. It says that the number of clusters can be calculated by

`k = (n/2)^0.5`

where n is the total number of elements from your sample.
You can check the veracity of this information on the following paper:

http://www.ijarcsms.com/docs/paper/volume1/issue6/V1I6-0015.pdf

There is also another method called G-means, where your distribution follows a Gaussian Distribution or Normal Distribution.
It consists of increasing k until all your k groups follow a Gaussian Distribution.
It requires a lot of statistics but can be done.
Here is the source:

http://papers.nips.cc/paper/2526-learning-the-k-in-k-means.pdf

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know the numbers of the clusters k to provide as parameter to k-means so there are four ways to find it automaticaly:

- G-means algortithm:  it discovers the number of clusters automatically using a statistical test to decide whether to split a k-means center into two. This algorithm takes a hierarchical approach to detect the number of clusters, based on a statistical test for the hypothesis that a subset of data follows a Gaussian distribution (continuous function which approximates the exact binomial distribution of events), and if not it splits the cluster. It starts with a small number of centers, say one cluster only (k=1), then the algorithm splits it into two centers (k=2) and splits each of these two centers again (k=4), having four centers in total. If G-means does not accept these four centers then the answer is the previous step: two centers in this case (k=2). This is the number of clusters your dataset will be divided into. G-means is very useful when you do not have an estimation of the number of clusters you will get after grouping your instances. Notice that an inconvenient choice for the "k" parameter might give you wrong results. The parallel version of g-means is called [p-means](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=5999830). G-means sources: 
  [source 1](https://blog.bigml.com/2015/02/24/divining-the-k-in-k-means-clustering/)
  [source 2](https://support.bigml.com/hc/en-us/articles/207435995-Which-algorithm-should-I-use-K-means-or-G-means-)
  [source 3](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2526-learning-the-k-in-k-means.pdf)
- [x-means](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.19.3377): a new algorithm that efficiently, searches the space of cluster locations and number of clusters to optimize the Bayesian Information Criterion (BIC) or the Akaike Information Criterion (AIC) measure. This version of k-means finds the number k and also accelerates k-means.
- Online k-means or Streaming k-means: it permits to execute k-means by scanning the whole data once and it finds automaticaly the optimal number of k.  Spark implements it.
- [MeanShift algorithm](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1000236): it is a nonparametric clustering technique which does not require prior knowledge of the number of clusters, and does not constrain the shape of the clusters. Mean shift clustering aims to discover “blobs” in a smooth density of samples. It is a centroid-based algorithm, which works by updating candidates for centroids to be the mean of the points within a given region. These candidates are then filtered in a post-processing stage to eliminate near-duplicates to form the final set of centroids. Sources: [source1](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MeanShift.html), [source2](https://www.inf.tu-dresden.de/content/institutes/ki/is/VORTRAG/Vortrag_Huong_Nguyen.pdf), [source3](http://jamesxli.blogspot.com/2012/03/on-mean-shift-and-k-means-clustering.html)

Answer (score 3):

First build a [minimum spanning tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree) of your data.
Removing the K-1 most expensive edges splits the tree into K clusters,
so you can build the MST once, look at cluster spacings / metrics for various K,
and take the knee of the curve.

This works only for [Single-linkage_clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-linkage_clustering),
but for that it's fast and easy. Plus, MSTs make good visuals.
See for example the MST plot under
[stats.stackexchange visualization software for clustering](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/visualization-software-for-clustering).

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised nobody has mentioned this excellent article:
http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/papers/PhamDN05-kmeans.pdf

After following several other suggestions I finally came across this article while reading this blog:
https://datasciencelab.wordpress.com/2014/01/21/selection-of-k-in-k-means-clustering-reloaded/

After that I implemented it in Scala, an implementation which for my use cases provide really good results. Here's code:

```
import breeze.linalg.DenseVector
import Kmeans.{Features, _}
import nak.cluster.{Kmeans => NakKmeans}

import scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

/*
https://datasciencelab.wordpress.com/2014/01/21/selection-of-k-in-k-means-clustering-reloaded/
 */
class Kmeans(features: Features) {
  def fkAlphaDispersionCentroids(k: Int, dispersionOfKMinus1: Double = 0d, alphaOfKMinus1: Double = 1d): (Double, Double, Double, Features) = {
    if (1 == k || 0d == dispersionOfKMinus1) (1d, 1d, 1d, Vector.empty)
    else {
      val featureDimensions = features.headOption.map(_.size).getOrElse(1)
      val (dispersion, centroids: Features) = new NakKmeans[DenseVector[Double]](features).run(k)
      val alpha =
        if (2 == k) 1d - 3d / (4d * featureDimensions)
        else alphaOfKMinus1 + (1d - alphaOfKMinus1) / 6d
      val fk = dispersion / (alpha * dispersionOfKMinus1)
      (fk, alpha, dispersion, centroids)
    }
  }

  def fks(maxK: Int = maxK): List[(Double, Double, Double, Features)] = {
    val fadcs = ListBuffer[(Double, Double, Double, Features)](fkAlphaDispersionCentroids(1))
    var k = 2
    while (k <= maxK) {
      val (fk, alpha, dispersion, features) = fadcs(k - 2)
      fadcs += fkAlphaDispersionCentroids(k, dispersion, alpha)
      k += 1
    }
    fadcs.toList
  }

  def detK: (Double, Features) = {
    val vals = fks().minBy(_._1)
    (vals._3, vals._4)
  }
}

object Kmeans {
  val maxK = 10
  type Features = IndexedSeq[DenseVector[Double]]
}
```

Comment: Implmented in scala 2.11.7 with breeze 0.12 and nak 1.3

Comment: Hi @eirirlar I am trying to implement the same code with Python - but I couldn't follow the code in the website. See my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729826/python-k-means-clustering

Comment: @ImranRashid Sorry I only tested with 2 dimensions, and I'm not a Python expert.

Answer (score 3):

If you use MATLAB, any version since 2013b that is, you can make use of the function `evalclusters` to find out what should the optimal `k` be for a given dataset.

This function lets you choose from among 3 clustering algorithms - `kmeans`, `linkage` and `gmdistribution`.

It also lets you choose from among 4 clustering evaluation criteria - `CalinskiHarabasz`, `DaviesBouldin`, `gap` and `silhouette`.

Answer (score 2):

I used the solution I found here : http://efavdb.com/mean-shift/ and it worked very well for me :

```python
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import MeanShift, estimate_bandwidth
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import cycle
from PIL import Image

#%% Generate sample data
centers = [[1, 1], [-.75, -1], [1, -1], [-3, 2]]
X, _ = make_blobs(n_samples=10000, centers=centers, cluster_std=0.6)

#%% Compute clustering with MeanShift

# The bandwidth can be automatically estimated
bandwidth = estimate_bandwidth(X, quantile=.1,
                               n_samples=500)
ms = MeanShift(bandwidth=bandwidth, bin_seeding=True)
ms.fit(X)
labels = ms.labels_
cluster_centers = ms.cluster_centers_

n_clusters_ = labels.max()+1

#%% Plot result
plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()

colors = cycle('bgrcmykbgrcmykbgrcmykbgrcmyk')
for k, col in zip(range(n_clusters_), colors):
    my_members = labels == k
    cluster_center = cluster_centers[k]
    plt.plot(X[my_members, 0], X[my_members, 1], col + '.')
    plt.plot(cluster_center[0], cluster_center[1],
             'o', markerfacecolor=col,
             markeredgecolor='k', markersize=14)
plt.title('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to use [Silhouette Coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette_(clustering)) to find the optimal cluster number(K). Details explanation is [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10540/how-to-interpret-mean-of-silhouette-plot).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a matrix of data called `DATA`, you can perform partitioning around medoids with estimation of number of clusters (by silhouette analysis) like this:

```
library(fpc)
maxk <- 20  # arbitrary here, you can set this to whatever you like
estimatedK <- pamk(dist(DATA), krange=1:maxk)$nc
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible answer is to use Meta Heuristic Algorithm like Genetic Algorithm to find k.
That's simple. you can use random K(in some range) and evaluate the fit function of Genetic Algorithm with some measurment like Silhouette
And Find best K base on fit function.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette_(clustering)

Answer (score 1):

```
km=[]
for i in range(num_data.shape[1]):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=ncluster[i])#we take number of cluster bandwidth theory
    ndata=num_data[[i]].dropna()
    ndata['labels']=kmeans.fit_predict(ndata.values)
    cluster=ndata
    co=cluster.groupby(['labels'])[cluster.columns[0]].count()#count for frequency
    me=cluster.groupby(['labels'])[cluster.columns[0]].median()#median
    ma=cluster.groupby(['labels'])[cluster.columns[0]].max()#Maximum
    mi=cluster.groupby(['labels'])[cluster.columns[0]].min()#Minimum
    stat=pd.concat([mi,ma,me,co],axis=1)#Add all column
    stat['variable']=stat.columns[1]#Column name change
    stat.columns=['Minimum','Maximum','Median','count','variable']
    l=[]
    for j in range(ncluster[i]):
        n=[mi.loc[j],ma.loc[j]] 
        l.append(n)

    stat['Class']=l
    stat=stat.sort(['Minimum'])
    stat=stat[['variable','Class','Minimum','Maximum','Median','count']]
    if missing_num.iloc[i]>0:
        stat.loc[ncluster[i]]=0
        if stat.iloc[ncluster[i],5]==0:
            stat.iloc[ncluster[i],5]=missing_num.iloc[i]
            stat.iloc[ncluster[i],0]=stat.iloc[0,0]
    stat['Percentage']=(stat[[5]])*100/count_row#Freq PERCENTAGE
    stat['Cumulative Percentage']=stat['Percentage'].cumsum()
    km.append(stat)
cluster=pd.concat(km,axis=0)## see documentation for more info
cluster=cluster.round({'Minimum': 2, 'Maximum': 2,'Median':2,'Percentage':2,'Cumulative Percentage':2})
```

Comment: you select data and library add  and you copy km=[] to Percentage':2}) last and run your python and see

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is using Self Organizing Maps (SOP) to find optimal number of clusters. The SOM (Self-Organizing Map) is an unsupervised neural
network methodology, which needs only the input is used to
clustering for problem solving. This approach used in a paper about customer segmentation.

The reference of the paper is

*Abdellah Amine et al., Customer Segmentation Model in E-commerce Using
Clustering Techniques and LRFM Model: The Case
of Online Stores in Morocco, World Academy of Science, Engineering and Technology
International Journal of Computer and Information Engineering
Vol:9, No:8, 2015, 1999 - 2010*

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'll make it simple and straight to explain, I like to determine clusters using 'NbClust' library.

Now, how to use the 'NbClust' function to determine the right number of clusters: You can check the actual project in Github with actual data and clusters - Extention to this 'kmeans' algorithm also performed using the right number of 'centers'.

Github Project Link: https://github.com/RutvijBhutaiya/Thailand-Customer-Engagement-Facebook

Comment: Instead of adding the github link, can you add a couple of key lines of code that can help others even if your code is not reachable?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the number of clusters by visually inspecting your data points, but you will soon realize that there is a lot of ambiguity in this process for all except the simplest data sets. This is not always bad, because you are doing unsupervised learning and there's some inherent subjectivity in the labeling process. Here, having previous experience with that particular problem or something similar will help you choose the right value.

If you want some hint about the number of clusters that you should use, you can apply the Elbow method:

First of all, compute the sum of squared error (SSE) for some values of k (for example 2, 4, 6, 8, etc.). The SSE is defined as the sum of the squared distance between each member of the cluster and its centroid. Mathematically:

SSE=∑Ki=1∑x∈cidist(x,ci)2

If you plot k against the SSE, you will see that the error decreases as k gets larger; this is because when the number of clusters increases, they should be smaller, so distortion is also smaller. The idea of the elbow method is to choose the k at which the SSE decreases abruptly. This produces an "elbow effect" in the graph, as you can see in the following picture:

[image]

In this case, k=6 is the value that the Elbow method has selected. Take into account that the Elbow method is an heuristic and, as such, it may or may not work well in your particular case. Sometimes, there are more than one elbow, or no elbow at all. In those situations you usually end up calculating the best k by evaluating how well k-means performs in the context of the particular clustering problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a Python package kneed (Kneedle algorithm). It finds cluster numbers dynamically as the point where the curve starts to flatten. Given a set of x and y values, kneed will return the knee point of the function. The knee joint is the point of maximum curvature. Here is the sample code.

```py
y = [7342.1301373073857, 6881.7109460930769, 6531.1657905495022,  
6356.2255554679778, 6209.8382535595829, 6094.9052166741121, 
5980.0191582610196, 5880.1869867848218, 5779.8957906367368, 
5691.1879324562778, 5617.5153566271356, 5532.2613232619951, 
5467.352265375117, 5395.4493783888756, 5345.3459908298091, 
5290.6769823693812, 5243.5271656371888, 5207.2501206569532, 
5164.9617535255456]

x = range(1, len(y)+1)

from kneed import KneeLocator
kn = KneeLocator(x, y, curve='convex', direction='decreasing')

print(kn.knee)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Leave here a pretty cool gif from Codecademy course:
[image]

The K-Means algorithm:

1. Place k random centroids for the initial clusters.
2. Assign data samples to the nearest centroid.
3. Update centroids based on the above-assigned data samples.

Btw, its not a explanation of full algorithm, its just helpful vizualization