# Text classification, preprocessing included

Tags: cluster-analysis, document-classification

Which is the best method for document classification if time is not a factor, and we dont know how many classes there are?

Comment: we also dont know the topics.

Comment: we dont know how many classes there are so clustering and then class labeling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my (incomplete) knowledge, Hierarchical Agglomerative Clustering is the best approach if you don't know how many classes. All of the other clustering algorithms either require prior knowledge of the number of buckets or some sort of cross-validation or other experimentation to determine a sensible number of buckets.

Comment: +1. With flat clustering though, sqrt(N) for N items is sometimes recommended as the number of clusters.

Comment: How about doing the actual clustering with  Growing Som algorithm and then using the bottom up approach of HAC? So that we dont have to guess the number of clusters either.

Comment: I have no background on Growing Som, so I can't advise you either way about that.

Comment: Its just a Self Organizing Map that chooses to grow resolution(clusters) where the mean error seems to be above a threshold. It is flat clustering but saves the topology so the hierarchy can be found by comparing the differences between neighboring clusters.

Answer (score 1):

A cross link: see [how-do-i-determine-k-when-using-k-means-clustering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793532/how-do-i-determine-k-when-using-k-means-clustering) on SO.

Comment: Thanks! I have already started with growing som though. It will be helpful for determining the starting grid size though.