# How to find optimal k in K-means method?

Tags: k-means

I have a data which is looks like

(0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1) 
(1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 )
(1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 )

the real data is 150*180 matrix. I want to use K-means method but don't know how to find optimal k. In some cases symbols "1" are grouped. Could someone please tell me how to find optimal k? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Optimal k is square root of number of data points but it will depend on your data set, a rule of thumb is also square root of half number of data points, see [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determining_the_number_of_clusters_in_a_data_set) and similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212690/how-to-optimal-k-in-k-means-algorithm)