# Population must be a sequence or set. For dicts, use list(d)

Tags: python

I try to excute this code and I get the error bellow, I get the error in the random function and I don't know how to fix it, please help me.

```
def load_data(sample_split=0.3, usage='Training', to_cat=True, verbose=True,
          classes=['Angry','Happy'], filepath='C:/Users/Oussama/Desktop/fer2013.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
    # print df.tail()
    # print df.Usage.value_counts()
    df = df[df.Usage == usage]
    frames = []
    classes.append('Disgust')
    for _class in classes:
        class_df = df[df['emotion'] == emotion[_class]]
        frames.append(class_df)
    data = pd.concat(frames, axis=0)
    rows = random.sample(data.index, int(len(data)*sample_split))
    data = data.ix[rows]
    print ('{} set for {}: {}'.format(usage, classes, data.shape))
    data['pixels'] = data.pixels.apply(lambda x: reconstruct(x))
    x = np.array([mat for mat in data.pixels]) # (n_samples, img_width, img_height)
    X_train = x.reshape(-1, 1, x.shape[1], x.shape[2])
    y_train, new_dict = emotion_count(data.emotion, classes, verbose)
    print (new_dict)
    if to_cat:
        y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
    return X_train, y_train, new_dict
```

I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "fer2013datagen.py", line 71, in <module>
   verbose=True)
   File "fer2013datagen.py", line 47, in load_data
   rows = random.sample(data, int(len(data)*sample_split))

   File"
   C:\Users\Oussama\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\random.py",
   line 311, in sample
   raise TypeError("Population must be a sequence or set.  For dicts, use
   list(d).")
TypeError: Population must be a sequence or set.  For dicts, use list(d).
```

Comment: What is `df` an abbreviation of, `dataframe`? `random.sample()` needs its first argument to be a sequence, so you'll need to convert `data` into a sequence (or set) in order to pass it without error.

Comment: have you tried `rows = random.sample(list(data.index), ...)` ?

Comment: df is DataFrame the function read_csv returns DataFrame

Comment: If you're dealing with `pandas` as @martineau is kind of getting at (the name `df` and `pd.concat` appears to be the case) - why not use the `.sample()` methods it supplies instead of the builtin `random.sample`, eg: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html

Comment: rows = random.sample(list(data.index), ...) worked thx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code here:

```
rows = random.sample(data.index, int(len(data)*sample_split))
```

But, error message shows

```
rows = random.sample(data, int(len(data)*sample_split))
```

Why different? Did you modify it? And what is the type of **data**  is? 
is it a list? or a dict?

And, error message has already told you how to fix it.
it means the first parameter of **random.sample** must be a sequence or set. For dicts, use list(Dict).

For example,

```
d = {'a':1,'b':2}
random.sample(list(d), 1)
```

instead of

```
random.sample(d, 1)
```