# How to find the optimal K for clustering?

Tags: java, cluster-analysis

I have a dataset with coordinates and my goal is to find the optimal K so I can cluster using K-Means.

I've already tried using Kneedle method via https://github.com/lukehb/137-stopmove/blob/master/src/main/java/onethreeseven/stopmove/algorithm/Kneedle.java but I can't seem to get it to work due to dependency issues.

What else can I try?

Comment: @Augusto It's not really software engineering. It's rather data science. And ... tadaaa... here it is: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5656/k-means-what-are-some-good-ways-to-choose-an-efficient-set-of-initial-centroids - similar questions are found on other network sites, e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/277007/rule-of-thumb-on-the-best-k-in-k-means-clustering - but also here on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793532/how-do-i-determine-k-when-using-k-means-clustering (Anyone opposed to closing this one as a duplicate of the latter?)

Comment: How about using VRC criterion? Or silhouette? Or Dunn?